# wxPython: Detecting mouse click on a bitmap

Tags: onclick, click, wxpython

I'm trying to detect a clic on a bitmap with wxpython.
The on_click procedure seems to run without clic, and not to run when clicking.
What do I do wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#

import os
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl as TC
import Image

filename="Raphael-Poli-angle.png"
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def on_clic(self):
       print "clicked"

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Choose Dot in Picture", size=(700,500))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        png = wx.Image(filename, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        image=wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, png, (1, 1), (png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight()))
        image.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_clic())
        self.Show(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to "input an event". The event comes from outside - depending on your action.
Change the "def on_clic..." to

```
  def on_clic(self, evt):
```

and also change "image.Bind..." to

```
    image.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_clic)
```

And if you change your on_clic to:

```
def on_clic(self, evt):
  x, y=evt.GetPosition()
  print "clicked at", x, y
```

...you can also get the position, where the image was clicked.

See: https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MouseEvent-class.html

Comment: Wow that's great!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

all event handlers must except the event as an argument. `on_clic` should be

```
def on_clic(self, event):
    print "clicked"
```

Comment: thanks for that answer, but could you please develop? What is event? What event should I input?

Comment: there are more than a few wxpython tutorials out there. Here is a quick overview of events https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wxpython/wxpython_event_handling.htm